# How many DFA's exist with two states over the input alphabet $\{0,1\}$?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, automata, formal-languages, regular-language

How many DFA's exist with two states over the input alphabet $\{0,1\}$?

---

My attempt :

Input set is given. So, we have 3 parts of DFA which we can change:

1. Start state
2. Transition Function
3. Final state

Start state can be chosen as any one among 2 in 2 ways.

Transition function is from $Q \times Z$ to $Q$, where $Q$ is the set of states and $Z$ is the alphabet. $|Q| = 2$, $|Z| = 2$. So, number of possible transition functions $= 2^{2 \times 2} = 2^{4}$

Final state can be any subset of the set of states including the empty set. With $2$ states, we can have $2^2 = 4$ possible sub states.

Thus total number of DFAs possible :

$=2\times2^4\times4=128$.

Where total 40 DFA's are accepting empty language.

> Can you explain in formal way, with a formula, please?

Comment: Your title and your question do not match: Two states or three states?

Comment: Sorry for typo. Thanks.

Comment: Your attempt seems to be very clean. What kind of formula do you wish?

Comment: Assume, if we have $n$ states, over total input alphabet is $m$ . Then what will be total number of DFAs and how many DFAs accepted empty languages ?

Comment: Why don't you apply the same argument to the general case?

Comment: Can I answer myself?

Comment: Yes, it is allowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution looks correct, If you are looking for a formula

For $k$ states and $i$ input alphabets

> $$k^{ki+1}\times 2^{k}$$

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but I think your solution is incorrect.
If with N states an alphabet of size Z, you have N * N * Z:
For each state,for each symbol in Z, there in a transition leading to one of N possible destination states. (n+1 if you allow the automaton to not be completely defined).